# Has social security been less volatile than other investments?

Tags: election

Social security benefits vary unpredictably by cohort, eligibility, etc.

Yet something like a rental property or dividend stock produces basically the same income all the time.

Is there any evidence that Social security is more secure?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about politics and political processes as described in the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help). If you want to give people investment advise, then [Personal Finance and Money Stack Exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com) might be a more appropriate site.

Comment: Dividend stocks do NOT produce basically the same income all the time.  Consider utility stocks after Enron: a lot went from  paying regular dividends to paying no dividends for years.

Answer (score 2):

I will need to find more modern estimates, but in 1998, conservative Heritage Foundation published [a study comparing SSI returns to other financial instruments](https://www.heritage.org/social-security/report/social-securitys-rate-return).

- Two-income households with children making $26,000 each: 1.23% return for SSI, 5% for 50/50 allocated portfolio (ironically, the latter figure still held true for such portfolios in 5 year period ending 2018).
- Single African American low earning males were even worse off (negative returns), due to lower life expectancy (SSI returns depend on how long you live past retirement).

Also, while this isn't personal finance SE, I'd like to note that "a rental property or a divident stock" is a rather poor primary way of investing for retirement for most people. A typical advice for the masses is 60/40 or 50/50 portfolio of high quality bonds (US Treasuries or highly rated corporate bonds and indexed low-cost funds).

Oh, and if you're not lucky, you just may end up investing in a bad period where your portfolio wouldn't fare so well (1930s come to mind).

Comment: The recommended portfolio is 70-75% stocks and 25-30% bonds.  Why?  This is the normal market allocation.  A 50/50 mix will be more consistent but consistently lower over any decent time interval.  As retirement approaches, it makes sense to build up a five year cash cushion.  So something like 60% stocks, 20% bonds, and 20% cash (e.g. bank CDs, a savings account, or even a checking balance).